# How closely do MGA94 and MGA2020 match when using Local datums (in central Victoria, Australia), ignoring continental drift?

Tags: coordinate-system, australia

Very new to Geolocation, but am I right in thinking that the "grids" used by MGA94 and MGA2020 *May* be extremely similar? Specifically, over the distance of a kilometer or less, roughly in the center of Victoria in Australia.

Case in point: an (informal) survey was done in the past and no note was kept of whether it was MGA94 or MGA2020. Six Temporary BenchMarks and one Permanent Benchmark were also included in the resulting Easting and Northing CSV file. If this legacy file is now aligned with the known seven local benchmarks, will using MGA94 or MGA2020 make more than a few (say, 5mm) difference in positioning? (Ignore height/AHD/vertical positioning).

I have learned that MGA94 and MGA2020 are +- 1.8m 'shifted' (due to continental drift) in a "Global" reference frame, but "locally" are they similar enough to ignore the difference?

Comment: GDA2020 is referenced to the International Terrestrial Reference Frame (ITRF) which allows for continetal drift globally; the datums are *entirely different*. The difference between GDA94 and GDA2020 is ~1.8m **both locally and globally**. If you have warped the survey to the known benchmarks then your survey is in the coordinate system that those benchmarks are recorded in. There is a NTv2 transformation matrix available from ICSM https://github.com/icsm-au/transformation_grids if you want to be super accurate.